# Does the EM algorithm converge exactly where a grid search on the marginalized likelihood converges?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, expectation-maximization, optimization

I have successfully implemented a grid search algorithm to estimate two parameters of a likelihood. I computed the likelihood $l(X;\theta)$ of observed data $X$ by integrating out the discrete unobserved data $Z$ like this: $l(X;\theta) = \sum_z \mathbb{P}(Z=z) \cdot l(X,Z;\theta)$. I start on a sparse, wide grid and go narrower on a second run, thus I get a fairly exact estimate for $\theta$.

Now, I am trying an EM algorithm on the exact same simulated data. It converges to a slightly different value for my two parameters $\theta$.

My question is: If both algorithms are implemented correctly, do they converge to exactly the same value for $\theta$? If that is true, something is wrong with my code.

Comment: Not guaranteed. Because EM can get stuck in local minima whereas grid search will come close to global with a fine grained grid.

Comment: Ah, true. But I let the EM algorithm start at the "global" maximum obtained from a grid search, and it still runs away a slight bit.

Comment: I don't know the underlying parameters of Z, but I can set up a grid of hypothetical/possible parameters, and then compute the likelihood for each parameter set. In each iteration, I use the parameters from the grid to integrate out Z. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

No, at least in general. When the problem you are trying to optimize is not convex, then you cannot make warranties about the solution you get. In this setting, you aim for good local extrema.

EM algorithm just ensures that at each iteration it will improve the estimates. But again, when the problem is not convex, you cannot say nothing about the global optimality of the solution.

Grid search is a greedy search algorithm, which is highly sensitive to the initial conditions.

The path that each method follows is different, and hence you are likely to get different solutions.